# How do I obtain a list of files that changed from svn over a date range?

Tags: svn, history, changelog

I'm attempting to pull a list of files that changed during a range of dates from svn.

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
svn diff -r {2009-08-10}:{2009-08-20} --summarize d:/libs/trunk
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what's wrong with this? it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @SilentGhost.  It works fine enough.  I wasn't sure if this was the best way to go about solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that my original method of programaticaly pulling data from svn is the best approach.

```
svn diff -r {2009-08-10}:{2009-08-20} --summarize d:/libs/trunk
```

where we are asking for a diff based on the range from the first date until the second date.  We ask for the summize option so we get eached changed file listed on it's own line.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this analysis a lot, I suggest fisheye: [link text](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I need to obtain these values programatically, not view them on a web page.