# SVN Export files within a particular date range

Tags: svn, export

I need to export all the files from SVN within a particular Date Range.
I have two questions regarding that.

1. How do I run the "`svn`" command? There are lot of sites which provided help on how to get the files in that range.(For example [How do I obtain a list of files that changed from svn over a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312991/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-files-that-changed-from-svn-over-a-date-range)) But I couldn't find how to run "`svn`" command
2. When exporting the files withing a date range, is it possible to maintain the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Unix-like scripting should help:

- I would first run an `svn export` command to get all the files (or just use your working copy).
- Then I would use `svn diff` to get the list of files to keep, as explained in the post you refer to.
- Then, using this list and the `xargs` command, copy all the files in the range to another location...